# Show that a function is well-defined

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, banach-spaces

The following is the [lemma](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2006-134-04/S0002-9939-05-08301-2/S0002-9939-05-08301-2.pdf) $2$.

[image]

I don't understand the last sentence. Which calculations give $L(x)=0$? And why this explains the well-definedness of the function $L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have
$$\|p_q(x)\| = \max_{s\ne q} \|x_s\| = \|x_r\| = \|x_q\|.$$
Hence,
$$1-\frac{\|p_q(x)\|}{\|x_q\|} = 0$$
and similarly for $r$.